# XML Scheme validation for different types

Tags: regex, xml, xsd, xsd-validation

Im trying to make an xml validiation code for e-mails which should be end with

- `@gmail.com`
- `@hotmail.com`
- `@yahoo.com`

I have implemented a code for gmail but I didn't figure out how can I create a pattern for 3 different type.

```xml
<xs:element name="email">
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="[A-Za-z_.0-9]+@gmail\.com"></xs:pattern>
        </xs:restriction>
     </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```xml
<xs:pattern value="[A-Za-z0-9_.]+@(gmail|hotmail|yahoo)\.com"></xs:pattern>
<xs:pattern value="[^@]+@(gmail|hotmail|yahoo)\.com"></xs:pattern>
```

The `(gmail|hotmail|yahoo)\.com` part will match `gmail.com`, `hotmail.com` or `yahoo.com`. Note you can only use *capturing* groups in XSD regex, so no `(?:...)` allowed.

Note `[^@]+` matches any one or more chars other than `@` and is a bit more loose email validation pattern, just in case you need to allow more chars in the user name.

Comment: Appreciate for your answer, I tried the "or" punctuation but I think my I had made a type because It did not work.Thx for the comment , now it's working fine .

Comment: I'm confused about the "^" mark because I have read that it's not allowed to use in XSD files. Is it true?

Comment: @MertPinarbasi You confuse a `^` used *outside* of brackets, and a `^` used *inside*. `^` outside of brackets means "start of string/line" in regex engines other than XSD/Lucene. `^` used as the first char inside bracket expressions means that the chars (set(s)) inside brackets are reversed, negated. The `^` outside of brackets should not be used in XSD regex. The one I used is fine.

Comment: Now I understand, I am so glad for your help but I have one more question since I am a beginner in XSD files it's very hard to do something even it's very basic operation.I used "\p{Lu}.*" this expression for names which should the uppercase for the first letter like (Jack) but I noticed it's for UTF-8 not regex , how can I do it by using regex.

Comment: @MertPinarbasi `"\p{Lu}.*"` should be fine to match any Unicode strings starting with an uppercase letter. If you do not want to match any uppercase letters, define a range. E.g., to only allow ASCII uppercase letters at the start, use `"[A-Z].*"`.